# Access POST data from a form in SonataAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a simple question, how can I access the raw POST data returned by a form in sonataAdmin?

I have a page that is creating forms using Javascript and I need to retrieve the data in those forms. The problem is that those forms are not attributes of the entity so I can't have Sonata admin linking them automatically for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base admin class provides a `getRequest` method which returns the `Request` object.

Something like...

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$postValue = $request->request->get('parameterName');
```

Comment: there is no data this way

Answer (score 4):

There even seems to be "smarter" and may be more secure version:

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    $uniqid = $this->getRequest()->query->get('uniqid');
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->request->get($uniqid);
    var_dump($formData);exit;
}
```

Source:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2610