# Add custom form field that is not in entity - Sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using Sonata Admin in my project. I need to render a field that doesn't belong to entity.

Consider entity **User** with fields **username** & **password**. But I also need a extra field as **hobby** in form but it is not needed in User entity.

```
    $formMapper
       ->add('username')
       ->add('password')
       ->add('hobby');
```

But I'm getting the symfony error as,

Neither the property "hobby" nor one of the methods "getHobby()", "hobby()", "isHobby()", "hasHobby()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\User".

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, you can probably do it with the answer provided by Bananaapple, but where you will store the hobby?

Comment: "hobby" is just a example field. I have several fields like hobby which needs to be stored in multiple tables.

Comment: ah, got you. then you need to use preUpdate hook to access the data and do something with it. :)

Comment: Yeah! I have used $this->getForm()->get('hobby')->getData(); to get the value of "hobby"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer for Symfony2 should still hold true if I am not mistaken: [How to add additional non-entity fields to entity form in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384414/how-to-add-additional-non-entity-fields-to-entity-form-in-symfony2)

> In symfony 2.1+, use mapped:
>
> ```
> $form = $this->createFormBuilder($promo)
>     ->add('code', 'text')
>     ->add('image', 'file', array(
>                 "mapped" => false,
>             ))
>     ->getForm();
> ```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#mapped

> **type**: `boolean` **default**: `true`
>
> If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the
>   object, you can set the `mapped` option to `false`.

So for your case it should be something like:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('username')
    ->add('password')
    ->add('hobby', null, [
        'mapped' => false
    ]);
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know the solution will be this simple. Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me, how to get the value of hobby in Sonata admin class?

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515172/access-post-data-from-a-form-in-sonataadmin